# Javascript error/WebResource not found on a page with RequiredFieldValidators

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, webresource.axd, file-not-found

A friend on mine is having an issue on one of his webforms, he referrs that everytime he loads one page containing RequiredFieldValidators the page throws the following Javascript/WebResource error:

> Mesagge: Syntax error
>   Líne: 3
>   Character: 1
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://localhost/miproyecto/WebResource.axd?CCL=ynu3FmO0gS8j

I thought that the issue could be related to a forms authentication problem so He allowed the resource to be a permitted file like this:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/105101/forms-authentication-using-login-control

However the problem persists

I wonder if there is a way to get rid of the issue.

Regards,
CR

Edit:Forgot to mention that when he comments the RequiredFieldValidators on the page, the error is gone. But the idea is to keep them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He had a .js file linked to the page and this was causing the error. Once it was commented the page worked.

Thanks!